# Canvas app UI messed up in IE 9, worked correctly in IE 8, rendered properly in Firefox. Anyone experienced this issue? Please suggest

Tags: canvas

I am trying to use canvas app on account detail page and caught in UI issue that canvas app UI messed up in IE 9, worked correctly in IE 8, rendered correctly in Firefox. Anyone experienced this issue? Please suggest.

**In firefox:**

[image]

**In IE 9:**

[image]

Although IE 9, 10 are in the supported browsers list for canvas, it is still not a full-fledged feature in Salesforce i think. This has been a challenge for the past two days as i am struggling to find a solution or fix for this issue as i am not sure the root cause of the issue. Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 2):

The key to note here is that canvas is not involved with any of the screens that you showed.  The UI you are displaying is UI served from the SAP side inside a browser iFrame.  If there are rendering issues, it would be from the SAP side.  Have you made sure the SAP WebdynPro code works properly in those browsers outside of canvas?  Perhaps spin up a standalone webpage (outside of salesforce) and launch the SAP site inside of an iframe?  My guess is that you will see the same issues.

The same will apply with SSL and cert issues.  You have to make sure your SAP certs and SSL is set up to work in standard HTTPS in iFrames.

When we say the browsers are supportedwith canvas, what that means is the canvas SDK works with those browsers.  Specifically, we are using windows.postMessage() to pass events and messages across the domains, so we have to make sure the browser supports that feature.  You still have to make sure the UI you are trying to display works as expected inside multiple browsers and in an iFrame.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I would create a separate web page out from Salesforce environment with an iFrame and try to display the SAP UI as per your suggestions and would get back to you.